# Is Carthian rule more like democracy or anarchy?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem, vampire-the-requiem-2e

I've been reading through *Vampire: the Requiem* 2nd edition, and I'm a bit perplexed about the Carthians. It makes the Carthians sound like freedom fighters who've little idea of how to rule once in power. My understanding of them from the 1st edition was that they were more democratic in nature, to contrast with the dictatorial Invictus. Perhaps the first Carthian book makes this make more sense, or I haven't gotten far enough in 2nd edition.

Has this changed in 2e? Or perhaps my recollection of 1e is flawed? How should the Carthian leadership be portrayed when they're in charge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Carthians are about revolution.

All the things you're saying are true to some degree. The nature of the Carthian Movement, as developed in their solo book and in works like *Coteries*, is that they're looking to try something **new**, in contrast to the dynasty/faith hegemony put forward by the Invictus and the Lancea Sanctum for hundreds of years. The Carthians are interested in community, solidarity, and revolutionary activity; their cities can be democratic, but just as often you'll see elements of socialism or communism (there's a reason why it's the Carthian *Manifesto*, after all). The "revolution" aspect is played up more strongly in 2nd Edition, but it's been there all along.

Comment: see, now I want to know what vampire communism is, everyone gets a lick off the same lickstick? the licksticks are provided equally? socialist, if you can't get your own licksticks you can have some of ours? (kinda joking, answer not required to that)

Comment: @xenoterracide Well, as a start, you'd probably have herds maintained in common, so that consumption could be regulated and the area not overtaxed or degraded. Rather than red rent paid to a Prince, you'd have a council of some sort where officers made decisions collaboratively and were chosen based on merit rather than connections or power or age. Granted, it would work about as well in practice as most kinds of vampire government, but if you're young, eager, and creative, you could see the advantages.

Comment: oddly afaik, all actual communist governments are actually dictatorships...not saying that's what communism is defined as, just how it's been executed. not playing VtR anyways, so I don't have to delve that far into this.